# postresql - How to recovery DB after system re-install

Tags: postgresql

I had to reinstall the system on my laptop and change ssd (C:). My postgres was installed on another disc (D:), this drive was fine and I still use it, but the Postgres client was deleted with system reinstallation.

i don't have any backup of DB.

Now I wonder if there is any option to copy/recover data from old postgres (I have all the folders)?

Can I install postgres in the same place it used to be on the hard drive (D:)? or it wont work or overwrite existing data ??

Answer (score 1):

pg data is stored under `D:\PostgreSQL\13\data` unless you configured it elsewhere, backup the entire `PostgreSQL\13` folder just in case, reinstall the same version and put the data back, should work